# Querying declared variable in Postgres gives "error: relation "XXX" does not exist"

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, triggers

I'm creating a Trigger Using NODE JS in Postgres, and when running the following query :

```
const SQL_QUERY = '...............';  // **SOME SQL THAT RETURNS A VALID DATA !!!**

const EmployeesTrigger = `
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UPDATE_EXMPLOYYEES() RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
  $$
      DECLARE
          PAYLOAD JSONB;
      BEGIN
          SELECT json_agg(groupperSubquery)
          INTO PAYLOAD
          FROM (
            ${SQL_QUERY}
          ) groupperSubquery;         
          IF PAYLOAD IS NOT NULL THEN
            UPDATE "employees" SET "employeeLeft" = TRUE WHERE "employeeId" IN (SELECT "employeeId" FROM "PAYLOAD");
            RETURN NULL;
          END IF;
          RETURN NULL;
      END;
  $$ 
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
`;
```

I get the error:

```
relation "PAYLOAD" does not exist
```

What's wrong with the query ?

Comment: What is `${SQL_QUERY}` at runtime? Why are you using a `TRIGGER` here at all (I'm asking because Triggers are generally a bad idea) - and why are you replacing raw source-code instead of making it a parameterized query with `SQL_QUERY` (or its resultset) passed-in as a parameter instead? ...methinks you're going to have some crazy query-plan caching...

Comment: @Dai: It's a query that returns a valid data , you can ignore it.

Comment: PAYLOAD is not a table, you can't use FROM to extract data from this variable. And since this a piece of json, your WHERE condition will most likely fail. You have use the json operators and functions to tell the database what to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-quoting the `PAYLOAD` variable confuses PostgreSQL, making it think you have some column in mind.

You can access `"employeeId"` key in your `PAYLOAD` via a [`[]` subscript](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSONB-SUBSCRIPTING) and use [`?` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) to see if `"employeeId"` of table `"employeeId"` is in that list: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y33qLUH3)

```
const EmployeesTrigger = `
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UPDATE_EXMPLOYYEES() RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
  $$
      DECLARE
          PAYLOAD JSONB;
      BEGIN
          SELECT json_agg(groupperSubquery)
          INTO PAYLOAD
          FROM (
            ${SQL_QUERY}
          ) groupperSubquery;         
          IF PAYLOAD IS NOT NULL THEN
            UPDATE "employees" 
            SET "employeeLeft" = TRUE 
            WHERE PAYLOAD['employeeId'] ? "employeeId";
            RETURN NULL;
          END IF;
          RETURN NULL;
      END;
  $$ 
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
`;
```

[`jsonpath`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH) function [`jsonb_path_exists()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.5.11.2.2.17.1.1.1) will be less convenient in this case, but it's good to promote for its flexibility:

```sql
WHERE jsonb_path_exists( PAYLOAD
                       ,'$.employeeId[*] ? (@==$var)'
                       ,'{"var":"'||"employeeId"||'"}')
```